# How to respond to any kind of interruption?

Tags: iphone

My app is playing a pretty complex animation. It's like a flipbook.

What I do is: I have a huge loop with selectors, and after every delayed call the next one is called.

Now someone calls the user and the device suddenly shows up this fat green status bar and maybe some big pick-up-the-phone-call overlay. Or: The alarm clock rings, and a big alert sheet appears in front of just about everything.

It would be great to just pause the whole animation in case of ANY interruption. Probably I've also missed like 5 more possible interruptions.

How are you doing that? How do you get notified for all interruptions and then call one single -stopEverything method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the app becomes inactive, the [UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification local notification](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW59) will be posted. In the opposite suituation, the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notification will be posted.

Your animation logic can listen to this and respond appropriately. There is an [`+setAnimationsEnabled:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW42) to kill all current and future animations, but there isn't a documented "global pause" method.

Comment: when killing also future animations, the app must be restarted in order to be able to play animations again?

Comment: @mystify: I mean, calling `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]` will stop all current animation and prevent future animations from starting. Call `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]` to return to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the animation, you might be better off using CoreAnimation directly by using a single CAKeyframeAnimation on the view's -layer rather than having one animation's completion selector start another animation.